# Boost graph: Iterating through all vertices and printing adjacent vertices

Tags: c++, boost, graph, adjacency-list

I want to print all vertices with their adjacent vertices. I found some examples online on how to do that, yet it won't work for me. I am getting the error, that the ++ operator cannot be used on ai. Also I think it needs to be `vertex_idMap[*ai]` and not `vertex_idMap[ai]` but this prompts an error. Does anyone know why this is wrong?

```
typedef adjacency_list<vecS, listS, directedS, VertexIDPorperty, EdgeWeight> Graph;  //the type of g
graph_traits <Graph>::vertex_iterator i, end;
graph_traits <Graph>::adjacency_iterator ai, a_end;
for (boost::tie(i, end) = vertices(g); i != end; ++i) {
    std::cout << vertex_idMap[*i];
    for (; ai != a_end; ++ai) {   //the ++ai seems to be wrong?
        std::cout << vertex_idMap[ai];
        if (boost::next(ai) != a_end)
            std::cout << ", ";
    }
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: The danger of "examples on the internet". Where was this found?

Comment: To your [question that you just deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50452884/boost-bfs-create-predecessor-map): you need to make `&p[0]` into an explicit propertymap: `boost::make_iterator_property_map(p.begin(), indexMap)` - see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4cbeaf0eabfb7c1b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observations:

1. Where's the rest of the code? It obviously depends on the types used.
2. `ai` and `a_end` aren't initialized (perhaps you didn't actually mean the code doesn't compile, and this was your whole problem)
3. `vertex_idMap[ai]` will not compile, as a `vertex_iterator` is not a valid `vertex_descriptor`

Here's a fixed example with the missing bits imagined:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6fceeb5c485ecd49)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using VertexIDPorperty = boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, int>;
using EdgeWeight       = boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double>;
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::directedS, VertexIDPorperty, EdgeWeight> Graph;

Graph sample();

int main() {
    Graph g = sample();
    auto vertex_idMap = get(boost::vertex_index, g);
    boost::graph_traits <Graph>::vertex_iterator i, end;
    boost::graph_traits <Graph>::adjacency_iterator ai, a_end;

    for (boost::tie(i, end) = vertices(g); i != end; ++i) {
        std::cout << vertex_idMap[*i] << ": ";

        for (boost::tie(ai, a_end) = adjacent_vertices(*i, g); ai != a_end; ++ai) {
            std::cout << vertex_idMap[*ai];
            if (boost::next(ai) != a_end)
                std::cout << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Implementing `sample()` to create a random graph:

```
#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>
#include <random>

Graph sample() {
    Graph g;
    std::mt19937 prng { std::random_device{}() };

    generate_random_graph(g, 10, 20, prng);
    int id = 0;
    for (auto vd : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g))) {
        put(boost::vertex_index, g, vd, ++id);
    }

    return g;
}
```

It prints something like:

```
1: 9, 9, 4
2: 6
3: 
4: 
5: 9, 9, 8, 9
6: 9, 3, 1
7: 2, 10
8: 6
9: 8
10: 7, 3, 8, 1, 4
```

### Out Of The Box

Printing a graph can be done simpler:

```
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
// ...

int main() {
    print_graph(sample());
}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91bc823ec4332fc3)</kbd>**

```
1 --> 
2 --> 3 10 9 6 6 10 
3 --> 8 
4 --> 
5 --> 4 
6 --> 1 5 8 
7 --> 4 9 2 2 1 
8 --> 6 
9 --> 5 7 
10 --> 7
```

Comment: The properties you assumed were indeed the ones that I used, sorry for not giving the whole code. This actually helped a bunch, thank you!